# Omit one parameter from view in Django?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, url-pattern

In `urls.py` `urlpatterns` I have such declaration:

```
url(r'^product-(\d+)-([a-zA-Z_]+)$', 'product', name="product"),
```

Second group in regexp is SEO name not needed in view.

In view I have:

```
def product(request, product_id, suffix):
```

but suffix is neither required nor used by me. It's there only for SEO.

Is there any way to get rid of this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis around the SEO name:

```
url(r'^product-(\d+)-[a-zA-Z_]+$', 'product', name="product"),
```

Now the pattern will not be captured and passed on to your view.

If grouping *is* required, use a non-capturing group (`(?:...)` instead of `(...)`):

```
url(r'^product-(\d+)-(?:[a-zA-Z_]+)$', 'product', name="product"),
```